# Allocate several GBs of memory for std::vector

Tags: c++, list, memory, vector, std

I need to acquire several GB of data from a sensor. When I tried to allocate a big array with malloc  (10 or more GB. My system has 32GB) it returns NULL. So I thought the problem could be solved with a linked list of iterators to vectors.

However I don't know how to set this up. I tried declaring "
list< vector::iterator >" but I can't allocate the memory for each vector (e/o should have 1000~2000 elements). Do you know any way to do this or maybe a better solution for this big memory allocation?

Comment: If you don't need contiguous memory you could try a `deque`, it allocates in smaller chunks.

Comment: *"My system has 32GB"* - RAM, I assume. RAM is irrelevant to all of this. You need to understand virtual memory management, and how address space imposes the true limit.

Comment: Why do you want to use a list of iterators instead of e.g. a vector of vectors? (Thats essentially what a deque is, but It not sure, what the chunk size is.

Comment: You will need to use an OS function that reserves that much memory (so no other applications can use it).  Also look into how to turn off *virtual memory* and *paging*.  You may have to wait for other programs to terminate or force other programs to terminate so you can grab their memory.

Comment: @IInspectable if they can allocate 9 GB but not 10 GB, then the problem is not address space. Remains to be seen if that's the case.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews why would that be necessary? Virtual memory vs. physical memory should be transparent to the application.

Comment: @IInspectable: Are you saying, the OP is probably compiling for 32bit or what are you aiming at?

Comment: @MarkRansom: My understanding is that the OP wants one huge block of memory that isn't paged to the hard drive.  There is a noticeable difference in execution time between virtual and physical memory.  Virtual memory has a larger overhead (either to fetch data from hard drive directly or to swap out an area to the hard drive).

Comment: I cant allocate more than 2GB. I dont even need it to be contiguous, just need chunks of 1000~2000 elements of contiguous memory to perform fast copies from sensor buffer.
This code is giving "std::bad_alloc"
    list< vector<int> > j(300000000);

    for (auto i : j){
    i.reserve(700);
}

Comment: @papanoel87 if you can't get more than 2GB then you probably have a 32 bit OS or application build. Move everything to 64 bit and come back if you still have a problem. And please define "fast", it's not a very precise term - computers are blindingly fast these days for most operations, even without optimizing.

Comment: I'm under a 64bit windows. Could it be compiling in 32 bits? I'm using codeblocks

Comment: 64-bit Windows supports a 32-bit execution environment (WoW64). Running a 32-bit application on 64-bit Windows also limits the address space to 2GB, unless the LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE flag is set in the image header. In that case you'll get 4GB of address space. Address space is not guaranteed to be available in a contiguous block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a 64-bit operating system, then malloc should be able to allocate the large size with no problem.

For example, this code runs on my windows machine (64-bit windows) and allocates 10GB of ram flawlessly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    long int size = 10L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    printf("size = %ld\n", size);
    char *x = (char *)malloc(size);
    printf("x = 0x%lx\n", x);
    long int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i += 1024*1024) {
        x[i] = 'h';
    }
    printf("Done1\n");
}
```

However, if you have a 32-bit operating system, you'll be in trouble, and can't allocate over some limit (maybe 3 GB, but probably system dependent)

In that case, you'll need to write your data to a file instead.

However, if you're using a fat filesystem, then you can't write to a file that big either.  In that case, you'd have to split the data among many files under 2gb in size.

You'd want to actually check the malloc result for NULL to make sure the malloc works and memory could be grabbed.

Comment: What happens if the block cannot be obtained because other applications are using the memory?

Comment: @Thomas: Uhm, welcome to the 21st century, where we have process isolation. Each process has it's very own address space! It's all the rage!

Comment: I'm under a 64bit windows. Could it be compiling in 32 bits? I'm using codeblocks

Comment: @papanoel87, that's your problem!, the codeblocks says, "NOTE: The codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup.exe file includes the GCC compiler and GDB debugger from TDM-GCC (version 4.7.1, 32 bit). The codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup-TDM-GCC-481.exe file includes the TDM-GCC compiler, version 4.8.1, 32 bit. While v4.7.1 is rock-solid (we use it to compile C::B), v4.8.1 is provided for convenience, there are some known bugs with this version related to the compilation of Code::Blocks itself..  So it's the 32bit compiler.  voila!  Use a 64-bit compiler and you'll be fine

Comment: Even under 64 bit OS and compilation, the application will only be given 2 GB max of ram, unless the "large address space aware" flag is set. Then it can allocation a maximum of 8 TB of memory (7 TB on  Intel Itanium-based systems).

Comment: What are you using to compile that piece of code? I'm getting error in (void*) to (char *) conversion.

Comment: I'm using just the cygwin gcc compiler.  looks like you must be using a c++ compiler, so just do a cast like this:  char *x = (char *) malloc(size);

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used my former code and I got up to 30GB of memory correctly allocated.

Comment: @StarPilot: [/LARGEADDRESSAWARE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz223b1z.aspx) is enabled by default for 64-bit builds, using Microsoft's toolchain. I'd would hope that Code::Blocks uses equally sane defaults (I know, it probably doesn't...).

Comment: @IInspectable: So what you are telling me is that in the 21st century, we can have multiple tasks demanding 64GB and they will all be satisfied without virtual memory?  Wow, I really want to know how this works, without virtual memory or memory maps.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Mapping IS the reason we have process isolation. Processes are isolated from each other because each has its own address space so they cannot access each other's memory.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I'm somewhat appalled and mildly shocked, that someone claiming to have *"over 30 years experience in C and C++"* **still** doesn't quite grok memory management, as implemented in pretty much every consumer OS out there. And yes, I am telling you, that multiple tasks can demand 64GB of memory each, and all memory requests can be satisfied. I'm not sure, how you came up with the restriction of not using virtual memory, or how you would force any given `malloc` implementation to not use virtual memory.

Answer (score 0):

I usually move to memory mapped files or shared memory maps for this kind of data volumes.

This way, you're not bound to the amount of physical (process) memory available at all. You can let the OS page in and out as required. Fragmentation becomes much less of an issue (unless you actually fragment the logical address space, which is quite hard to achieve on 64 bit architectures).

---

#### *More information*

I have quite a number of answers on SO that show examples of storing vectors and all manner of more complicated data structures in shared memory/mapped files. You might want to look for `mapped_file_device` (from Boost Iostreams) or `managed_shared_memory` and `managed_mapped_file` (from Boost Interprocess)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to allocation this space under Windows 64 bit OS. You will ALSO have to set "large address space aware" flag, otherwise you can only get 2 GB of RAM due to how the virtual memory system works on Windows.

You may want to look into using a memory mapped file, as suggested by sehe in his answer if you do not absolutely have to have one large 10 GB chunk of continuous memory. If you have to build your application for Windows 32 bit, then this will be the only answer, as Windows 32 bit normally only allows for 2 GB of memory, unless the option is set for "large address space aware" flag, at which point it will allow 3 GB of memory usage.

Comment: If the *Large Address Aware* flag is set in the PE header, a 32-bit process gets to use **4**GB of address space on a 64-bit Windows. It gets 3GB on a 32-bit Windows system booted with the /3GB boot.ini-switch. The standard way to deal with data caches larger than 4GB for a 32-bit process is by using the [Address Windowing Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366527.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

When you have to deal with large blocks of memory, you are better off skipping malloc altogether and going directly to the operating system calls for memory allocation.